# Delay between viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear with animated UIImageView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a controller that uses an animated UIImageView to display a sequence of 30 512 x 512 frames. When I run the application the view quickly does the following.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[self imageView] setAnimationImages:[[self dataModel] framesForLOOP]];
    [[self imageView] setAnimationDuration:2.5];
    [[self imageView] setAnimationRepeatCount:1];
    [[self imageView] startAnimating];
    NSLog(@"MARKER_001");
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    NSLog(@"MARKER_002");
}
```

This all works fine but what I am trying to work out is that after `viewDidLoad:` is called there is a 2 second delay before `viewDidAppear:` is called (between MARKER_001 and MARKER_002).

I was thinking there might be a delay setting up the frames `NSArray` or after calling `setAnimationImages:` or maybe after `startAnimating`.

Is there anyway to reduce/remove this delay, I would prefer to preload the animation at startup and take a hit there rather than having the delay when the viewController loads as it makes the button that fires the segue to instantiate the new controller feel laggy.

Comment: Can you compare that to the lag when the imageView stuff is commented out?  Let's first find out if that's the problem.

Comment: If I comment out the lines between [super viewDidLoad]; and NSLog(@"MARKER_001"); there is no delay. I would suspect the delay is basically the viewController setting up what it needs to behind the scenes to get the animated UIImageView on screen and playing.

Answer (score 2):

Just a few ideas:

1. reduce the pain - do you need 30x512x512?
2. distribute the pain - load the first image on viewWillAppear, kick off an operation to load the others and update the animation images as new images are ready (can supply code e.g. if needed)
3. move the pain - prepare the array of UIImages in app init.
4. dig deeper - let's have a look at the framesForLoop method, maybe there's some more opportunity to reduce/distribute/move the pain in there.

Comment: Thank you danh, these are very good points. The images don't need to be 512 they could be smaller, but as they are for an animated intro 512 is already quite small on the retina display. The method that you mention framesForLoop is actually an NSArray containing all the UIImages needed for the animated UIImageView. This was my first shot at stripping out some of the work and putting it right at the start under the loading/splash screen. I will take some of the pointers here and have a play tomorrow, see if I can tune things up a little more. Thanks again for your time, very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Note that even if you call `startAnimating` in `viewDidLoad`, the animation won't start there. You can't get an animation running in a controller which has not been not displayed yet.

You should call the `startAnimating` in `viewDidAppear` instead.

Two seconds delay between these two methods is not anything strange. The delay can be much longer or shorter, depending on what happens inside your application.
Measuring the time between two methods which are not connected doesn't make sense. What about measuring how much time the individual methods take?

If anything is laggy, you should probably paste all the code that happens between the user action and the moment when everything is displayed and the lag happens.

Comment: I am only following the logical flow, as I mentioned above without the UIImageView calls in there is zero delay. I was trying to find out if the delay way just unavoidable overhead or something that I could setup / cache elsewhere where maybe a slight delay is more acceptable. To be fair I would assume that when the controller loads the delay is moving the required frames to memory on demand, and not really something that can be sensibly pre-cached.

Comment: I am just telling you that there are big flaws in your question and your measurements and it's impossible to answer correctly.

Comment: I appreciate that, I was just trying to find out what iOS was doing behind the scenes at this point (its obviously setting up the view). As you suggested I have timed the methods involved and there does not seem to be any significant slow down there. Thank you for your answer, its a valid point.